# afterrender vs onkeypress

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a textbox which would have an ItemID of `NameId` when I try to retrieve it using an `afterrender` event it returns `undefined` but when I use let's say a `keypress` event using let's say an enter key it returns the expected value. Could someone explain how and why that's happening?

Here is a sample implementation:

afterrender event:

```
afterrenderTest: function (component, eOpts){
      var foo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#NameId')[0].value;
      console.log(foo); //returns undefined
```

onkeypress event:

```
onkeyPressTest: function (button, e, eOpts){
      var foo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#NameId')[0].value;
      if (e.getKey() === e.ENTER){
      console.log(foo); //returns a value
      }
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an "afterrender" event ?

Comment: Yes,  I am using sencha architect and it is on list of events available to use

Comment: These events are from the panel view if that makes sense.

Comment: This is an interesting information indeed. Can you see an event called "painted" in this list ? See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48115511/1636522.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After render will only return value if you pass textfield value in value config while declaring that. I suggest you should pass default value, like this:

```
 xtype: 'textfield',
 itemId:'NameId'
 fieldLabel: 'Name',
 value: 'XYZ',  // This should be declare
 listeners: {
   afterrenderTest: function (component, eOpts){
       var foo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#NameId')[0].value;
       console.log(foo); //Then it will return value
   }
}
```

I suggest you should use blur event instead on afterrender or keypress. It will return current textfield value on every tab click or lost focus. Check this:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
itemId:'NameId',
fieldLabel: 'Name',
listeners: {
  blur: function(field){
     var foo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#NameId')[0].value;
     console.log(foo); 
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I’m getting a value from another view to this view? Would blur be better than afterrender?

Comment: If you are trying to access values from **itemId** then it will access in same view not from another view. For that case **id** will works better.

Textfield **blur** event is always better for accessing textfield values.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that Sencha provides two different ExtJS "toolkits" called "Modern" and "Classic". What's weird is that they have the same version number, but they do not work the same... Indeed, the `afterrender` event seems to be available only in the Classic toolkit :

- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.Component.html
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.Component.html

As a workaround for the Modern toolkit you could patch the `Ext.Component` class like so :

```
Ext.define("My.override.Component", {
    override: "Ext.Component",
    afterRender: function () {
        this.callParent();
        this.fireEvent("afterrender");
    }
});
```

Then you can use the `Ext.Component` class like you always did :

```
Ext.create("Ext.Component", {
    id: "my-cmp",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function () {
            console.log("afterrender");
        }
    }
});
```

You can perform live experiments at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor. Thanks to the dropdown list at the top right corner of the screen you can switch between Classic and Modern. Refresh the entire page if you get the `Ext not defined` error - no comment x-)

However, patching the framework is probably a bad practice. You should better try to figure out if Sencha Architect is using either the Classic or the Modern toolkit, and if you can choose the toolkit you want to use. Also try the "painted" event instead of "afterrender" if available.

I can't check by myself since I don't have Sencha Architect installed. Keep me informed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation, textbox dont have 'value' property, it's only config. You should use getValue() method instead.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
title: 'Contact Info',
width: 300,
bodyPadding: 10,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    listeners:{
        afterrender: function(one,two,three){
            console.log(one.value); //undefined
            console.log(one.getValue()); //" " //empty string
        }
    }
}]
});
```

You could use value property only if you send it in config, but this is undocumented use, and it is recommended to use the getValue() method instead.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
title: 'Contact Info',
width: 300,
bodyPadding: 10,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    value: 'Hello world',
    allowBlank: false,  // requires a non-empty value,
    listeners:{
        afterrender: function(one,two,three){
            console.log(one.value); //Hello world
            console.log(one.getValue()); //Hello world
        }
    }
}]
});
```